# I am looking to create a custom metric based on BigQuery SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, monitoring, monitor, observability

The requirement is to monitor the table **customer** which has a column **ingest_timestamp**.
I want to send an alert to the user if no data has arrived within last 24 hours. chatGPT has provided me this solution

```
You can set up an alert in Cloud Monitoring to monitor the ingest_timestamp column in the customer table and trigger an alert if no data has been processed for the previous day.

Here are the steps to set up the alert in Cloud Monitoring:

Create a metric that captures the maximum value of the ingest_timestamp column in the customer table. You can use the following query to create the metric:


SELECT MAX(ingest_timestamp) FROM `my_project.my_dataset.customer`

Set up an alert policy in Cloud Monitoring that uses the metric created in step 1. You can use the following configuration to set up the alert policy:

Condition: Single time series
Aggregator: Max
Time range: Last 24 hours
Threshold: No data received
Notification: Choose the notification channel to receive the alert
Save the alert policy.
```

However I do not seems to find any create metric button on Metric Explorer screen. What am I missing here or chatGPT is just making things up ?

Comment: You have option of creating Log Based metric. One example you can follow here
https://youtu.be/OSvD3NgoBB0

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am not looking for a log-based metric as it just gives me an idea if the table has been updated (which could be updated for various reasons), I am specifically interested to check ingestion_timestamp data. It's a question of "Observability". I wonder how people are implementing Observability on BigQuery.